# Для заданной точности eps написать функцию вычисления приближенного значения e

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

помогите решить задачу:
Для заданной точности eps написать функцию вычисления приближенного значения e^x по формуле 1+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...x^k/k!

Где |x^k/k!| <= eps
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мой код, в цикл уходит, не понимаю, как работать должно вообще, подскажите, в какую сторону копать

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "math.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    int fct(int nmb)
    {
        int f = 1;
        for(int i=1; i<=nmb; ++i) f *= i;
        return f;
    }
    
    double expnt(double x, double eps) {
        double res = 1;
        for(int k = 2; (abs(pow(x,k) / fct(k))) <= eps; k++)
            res += pow(x,k) / fct(k);
        return res;
    }

int main()
{   
    double eps, x;
    cout << "x= ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "eps= ";
    cin >> eps;
    
    cout << "e^x ~= " << expnt(x, eps); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double expnt(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = 1.0, term = 1.0;
    for(int n = 1; abs(term) > eps; ++n) sum += term *= x/n;
    return sum;
}
```

У вас неверная формула + скорее всего факториал переполняется. Вот верная формула для exp(x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли как то решение сделать именно через деление на факториал с функцией, а то сам ряд Тейлора сказал не использовать?

Comment: А деление на факториал - это что, не использование ряда Тейлора?!

Comment: Я пары гулял, глупец, изъясняюсь не так, извините, просто можно сам алгоритм расписать, если не трудно, как это работает вообще?

Comment: Отношение двух соседних членов ряда - n-го и n-1-го - равно x/n. Просто очередной член (переменная term) получается из предыдущего без длинного и ненужного вычисления степени и факториала.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Немного прошёлся по метке ряды, что ни вопрос - так под ним ваш ответ с критикой вычисления факториала и возведения в степень через pow. А вы упорный :D Интересно, сколько тактов процессора сберегли ваши ответы... :D

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Ну вот, смотрите - https://ideone.com/rAxUGm - понятно, что разница в 30 раз для этих с потолка взятых данных, для других будет иной... Кстати, сравните заодно длину кода :)

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл А вообще, я как-то девочек с соседнего кибфака еще на 1 курсе 40 лет назад на спор победил - у них была задача, кажется, какой-то ряд посчитать, взять пятую цифру, и вычислить какой-то интеграл на основе этой цифры. Пока они свое фортранили, я это же ухитрился в Б3-34 воткнуть *одной программой*... Так что когда я вижу, как *впустую* прогаживаются... уже **гига**байты и **гига**герцы - становится просто до боли обидно... Кстати, не менее обидно, когда вот так неверно в условии (!) ряд указывают. Птенцы гнезда ЕГЭшного...